# IBM Worklight 6.1 - How to detect the keyboard's "Search" button?

Tags: ios, keyboard, ibm-mobilefirst

We are developing a hybrid mobile app using IBM Worklight 6.1.

For iOS, how to handle "Search" button event from the soft keypad that is displayed?

Comment: if my answer helped resolve your problem, please mark as answered.

Answer (score 0):

"handle" is a bit vague... What are you trying to accomplish?
You shouldn't need to detect any button, if you invoke the correct keyboard for the specific need.

The search button in the iOS keyboard will only appear if your `input` tag is inside a `form` element.
For example:

```
// This will display a return button.
<input id="textField" type="text"/>

// This will display a search button.
<form>
    <input id="searchField" type="search"/>
</form>
```

In JavaScript, you can use the [jQuery `keypress`](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) event to trigger an action once the search button is tapped. For example:

```
$("#searchField").keypress(function() {
    alert("Handler for .keypress() called.");
});
```

You could also "detect" the "type" of the keyboard, in the case of "search", like the following (but this is kinda obvious...):

```
if ($("#searchField").attr("type") == "search") {
    alert("This search field is of type 'search'.");
}
```

Otherwise, you will need to implement native code (meaning a [Cordova plug-in](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#GS_native_to_hybrid)) to detect the type of the currently displayed keyboard and perform actions, etc...